# error TS2339: Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'DiseaseListComponent'

Tags: angular

So I have been having the following problem:

```
ERROR in src/app/disease/disease-list/disease-list.component.html:21:53 - error TS2339: Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'DiseaseListComponent'.

21   <mat-card class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage; else loading">
                                                   ~~~~~~~

src/app/disease/disease-list/disease-list.component.ts:10:16
10   templateUrl: './disease-list.component.html',
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component DiseaseListComponent.
```

Here is my code:

```
    <div *ngIf="(diseases$ | async) as diseases; else loadingOrError">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="2%">
        <app-add-disease (newDisease)="addNewDisease($event)"></app-add-disease>

        <mat-card>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput (keyup)='filterDisease$.next($event.target.value)' type="text" placeholder="filter" />
          </mat-form-field>

        </mat-card>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="start">
          <div class="disease" *ngFor="
        let localDisease of (diseases$ | async | diseaseFilter : filterDiseaseName)" fxFlex="0 0 calc(25%-0.5%)"
            fxFlex.xs="100%">
            <app-disease [disease]="localDisease"></app-disease>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #loadingOrError>
      <mat-card class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage; else loading">
        Error loading the disease list: {{ errorMessage }}. <br />
        Please try again later.
        <ng-template #loading>
          <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-card>
    </ng-template>
```

It basically cannot find the `#loading` part and I cant seem to figure out why. 
I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that `<ng-template #loading>` is defined inside `<mat-card class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage; else loading">` so when the `*ngIf` condition is false it will not exists in the DOM. You need to put it at the same level as `<mat-card class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage; else loading">` or above

```
<mat-card class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage; else loading">
  Error loading the disease list: {{ errorMessage }}. <br />
  Please try again later.
</mat-card>
<ng-template #loading>
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this fixed it :)